# Can't show Toast Notification if Param content greater than 430 Characters

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, notifications, toast

I'm developing wp8 app. I have some problem. I create Toast Notification for my app. then...

1. If my app in running: that ok.
2. But when my app close, or at home screen, or my phone is off. The Toast Notification can show if my param string is less than 430 characters, or no unicode character.

This is my server send toast code:

```
// Create the toast message.
string toastMessage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
            "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
               "<wp:Toast>" +
                    "<wp:Text1>" + TextBoxTitle.Text.ToString() + "</wp:Text1>" +
                    "<wp:Text2>" + TextBoxSubTitle.Text.ToString() + "</wp:Text2>" +
                    "<wp:Param>[My String]</wp:Param>" + 
              "</wp:Toast>" +
            "</wp:Notification>";
```

So my toast notification can alert in this cases:

```
"<wp:Param>[String great than 430 chars]</wp:Param>"

"<wp:Param>"Sài Gòn"</wp:Param>"
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm curious why you need such a long notification, given there isn't *that much* space to actually show it?

Comment: Also, for the unicode side of it, can you include the code that actually transmits the request to the server - it sounds like it may be due to a character encoding issue.

Comment: I need to send a JSON string. And Now I can redesign my system because it was publiced

Comment: I can't find documented limits, but they *used to be* 256 characters for the `<Param>` (according to https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/95d7d734-373f-4bd3-8a02-f829006bb658/payload-vs-url-length-limit-please-suggest?forum=wpnotifications)